# Correct syntax for defining the vertex of the graph of a cuadratic function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I got into a discussion with my math teacher. Given the function:

$$
f(x)=a(x-h)^2+k
$$

If $h = 3$, $k = 2$ and $a = 1$, then:

$$
f(x)=(x-3)^2+2
$$

We can agree that, when graphing the function, the coordinates of the vertex would be $(3,2)$. The thing is that my teacher wrote in the board that, then:

$$
\text{Vertex} = (h,k)
$$

I say it should be:

$$
\text{Vertex}=(-h,k)
$$

Which one is syntactically correct? Is the second expression "redundant" or something?

Answer (score 0):

The Vertex as shown here is an actual point and is the point where the quadratic function reaches its minimum value.  Given that this is a quadratic function, it has exactly one minimum, so only one representation is correct.

For the function $f(x)=(x-3)^2+2$, using $x=3$ produces $f(3)=(3-3)^2+2=2$ which is the point $(3,2)$.  But using $x=-3$ produces $f(-3)=(-3-3)^2+2=38$ which is the point $(-3,38)$ and is clearly not a minimum value for the function and is not equivalent to the point $(3,2)$.

The reason this is the case is due to the fact that in the original formulation, $h$ already has a negative applied to it.  In particular, this means that when $x=h$ the value of $a(x-h)^2=0$ which is exactly the $x$-value of the Vertex in all cases.  It is applied in this way so that $x$ can take on increasing values if $h$ takes on increasing values, the way that $y$ takes on increasing values if $k$ takes on increasing values.

So the answer is "no, this is not an equivalent way to represent the Vertex."